# How to update date automatically in mysql via php request

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Help me with php. 
How to update the "post_modified_gmt" value in the database every day so that the script itself knows what date is today (GMT)

```
        function setResultToArray($result) {
            $array = [];
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                $array[] = $row;
            return $array;
        }


        $mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'NameDB', 'password', 'login');
        $mysqli->set_charset('UTF8');



        /* Update */
        echo 'Update Query', "<br />";
        $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_modified_gmt` = '2020-05-16T14:31:10'");
        if ($result)
            echo 'Date upd', "<br />";

        $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Side note: You realize that you're updating your entire database, *right?*

Comment: I need the date itself to change every day to a new one automatically